# My Discord Music bot executes an object instead of text

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make a music bot, but it wont execute the song. Below is the code for the section which should gather the information and execute the song.

Can someone help me get this right? I'm not sure how to fix this issue as I don't know where the error starts.

I pasted also the handleVideo and the play class in the end so you know what happens there.

```
if (command === 'play') {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('I\'m sorry but you need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) {
            return message.channel.send('I cannot connect to your voice channel, make sure I have the proper permissions!');
        }
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
            return message.channel.send('I cannot speak in this voice channel, make sure I have the proper permissions!');
        }

        if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
            const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
            const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
            for (const video of Object.values(videos)) {
                const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
                await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
            }
            return message.channel.send(`✅ Playlist: **${playlist.title}** has been added to the queue!`);
        } else {
            try {
                var video = await youtube.getVideo(url);
            } catch (error) {
                try {
                    var videos = await youtube.searchVideos(searchString, 10);
                    let index = 0;
                    message.channel.send(`
__**Song selection:**__
${videos.map(video2 => `**${++index} -** ${video2.title}`).join('\n')}
Please provide a value to select one of the search results ranging from 1-10.
                    `);
                    // eslint-disable-next-line max-depth
                    try {
                        var response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg2 => msg2.content > 0 && msg2.content < 11, {
                            maxMatches: 1,
                            time: 10000,
                            errors: ['time']
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return message.channel.send('No or invalid value entered, cancelling video selection.');
                    }
                    const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);
                    var video = await youtube.getVideoByID(videos[videoIndex - 1].id);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return message.channel.send(' I could not obtain any search results.');
                }
            }
            return handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel);
        }
    }
async function handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    console.log(video);
    const song = {
        id: video.id,
        title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
        url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
    };
    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueConstruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true
        };
        queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);

        queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            queueConstruct.connection = connection;
            play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
            queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
        }
    } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        console.log(serverQueue.songs);
        if (playlist) return undefined;
        else return message.channel.send(`✅ **${song.title}** has been added to the queue!`);
    }
    return undefined;
});

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    console.log(serverQueue.songs);

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
        .on('end', reason => {
            if (reason === 'Stream is not generating quickly enough.') console.log('Song ended.');
            else console.log(reason);
            serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on('error', error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);

    serverQueue.textChannel.send(` Start playing: **${song.title}**`);


}
```

The error message:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:411:3)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:545:16)
    at new FfmpegProcess (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\FfmpegProcess.js:14:33)
    at FfmpegTranscoder.transcode (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\Ffmpeg.js:34:18)
    at MediaTranscoder.transcode (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\MediaTranscoder.js:27:31)
    at Prism.transcode (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\node_modules\prism-media\src\Prism.js:13:28)
    at AudioPlayer.playUnknownStream (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\AudioPlayer.js:97:35)
    at VoiceConnection.playStream (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:478:24)
    at play (C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExoBot-master\bot.js:322:44)
```

Comment: You can edit your question to include the code you forgot. No need to use pastebin.

Comment: okay didn't see that before. It's done now

Comment: @Orion Are you sure `ytdl(song.url)` returns a `string`, rather than some `object`?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but i try to parse it as string.

Comment: It did not work by parsing it to a string